# Problem with height adjustment of an <iframe> : scrollHeight returns 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, iframe

I'm working on a mailbox, i get a mail from a HTTP request and try to display it in a iframe, because it can be a plain text or HTML email.

There is no problem to display the content but i'm not able to adjust the height to that content. I always get a 0 from `contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight`.

I tried to see if it comes from the fact that the mail could be in plain text, but it's the same thing for an html email.

I know that the content is displayed because i manually edited the page to change the height and show the content. The only problem right now is the auto adjustment of this height.

By the way, the `iframe.contentWindow.document.body` is an `[Object HTMLBodyElement]`

```
$scope.iFrameDisplayMail = function (Mail_content) {

    var iframe = document.getElementById('mail-display');
    if (Mail_content.html != null) {
      iframe.contentWindow.document.write(Mail_content.html);
    } else {
      iframe.contentWindow.document.write(Mail_content.plain);
    }
    iframe.style.width = 'auto';
    alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
    iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();  
}
```

There is no error in the console about this.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your example, you can use:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('mail-display');
var scrollHeight = iframe.ownerDocument.body.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: not working, it's said that we can't get the parameter "document" of undefined

Comment: I fixed the answer to reflect the iframe var in the question. Should be ownerDocument instead of "parent".

Comment: This solution worked for me. It's not a fix to be exact, more like a workaround. iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight was returning 0 for me too, but ownerDocument always has the correct value.

Comment: this work but not perfect. It does not return the exact height of the content. for large content i still end up with scrollbars when using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found this question while researching how to fix it. In case it might help someone else, here's how I got it to work:

**TLDR**: Try adding an empty `<style></style>` tag to the HTML content of the Email you want to display in the iFrame if it doesn't have one.

I set the HTML content for the iFrame using `iFrame.contentWindow.document.write("Html-Content-From-Received-Email"`). As for you, this content would be displayed (if I changed the height manually when troubleshooting), but the `iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` returns 0, so I can't set my height correctly programmatically.

What I found is that this problem only occurred for HTML content that does not have a `<style></style>` tag - which is common for E-Mails, eg. sent from Thunderbird. When I added an empty `<style></style>` tag to the E-Mail-content I received (otherwise exactly the same), the correct scrollHeight was returned. So, for example, this E-Mail content would not work (scrollHeight=0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Das ist ein Test.</p>
    <p>Das ist ein Test.</p>
    <p>Das ist ein Test.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I add the `<style></style>` tag, it would work correctly and the correct scrollHeight would be returned:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style></style>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Das ist ein Test.</p>
    <p>Das ist ein Test.</p>
    <p>Das ist ein Test.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not a web expert, so I can't explain why exactly this works, but it cost me quite some time to fix this issue and I hope the solution that worked for me also helps someone else.

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work for me

Comment: For me, it continues to work - @MoSadeghipour, are you trying to display HTML or plain text? And which mail client are you testing with?